# Can I create a ZFS mirror in FreeNAS using different sized disks?

Tags: freenas, zfs, raid-z

I've just bought a new 4-bay N54L server for home use. I've upgraded it to 8G of RAM, which will permit me to run FreeNAS 9.1.x with ZFS.

I've loaded a new 2TB SATA disk plus a spare 250G disk into the server, and set about creating a mirrored volume. True, one wouldn't use non-matching sizes in real life, but it's just a test, and to familiarise myself with the web UI. (Once I am familar with it, I'll be using 4x2TB with RAIDZ-2, so long as I can get FreeNAS8 to work!).

However, the ZFS Volume Manager doesn't permit the disk count slider to go past 1, and thus only offers Stripe (plus Log, Cache and Spare) - I was hoping it would let me create a mirror of 250G (the full part of the smaller drive, and a small part of the large one). Am I missing an option here? Do RAIDZ-x (as [illustrated here](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Volumes#ZFS_Volume_Manager)) options become available when the right number/size of disks are inserted?

Here is the menu in action:

[image: Screenshot of ZFS Volume Manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the new ZFS Volume Manager in FreeNAS version 9.1.x. It looks like it will be fixed in (hopefully) the next release: https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/3274#note-3

Comment: Thanks Dave, and apologies; I don't believe I was alerted to your reply. I've not had chance to configure this server, but will do so in the next week or so. I'll be doing a reinstall with the latest version, which I expect has moved on since I last tried this!